# Can't add firebase-perf version 9.0.0 dependency

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

How can I tell what is the minimum version of `firebase-perf`?
I want to use version 9.0.0 and I get the error:

> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:9.0.0

I tried to add

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
      }
```

but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: The [initial beta release](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) of Firebase Performance was 10.2.6

Comment: There is no 9.0.0 version of Firebase Performance.  It was not part of the Firebase platform launch in May 2016 when 9.0.0 was released.  You will have to update your client SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this (inside app build.gradle):

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

//inside dependencies add the below

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.6.0'
```

and check this site for the guide:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android

Comment: I don't want to increase the version, I just want to know if there is version 9.0.0 for firebase performance.

Comment: u cannot use 9.0.0 not sure where you got that from.. if other firebase components are also version 11.6.0 then your gonna have to use 11.6.0 for firebase-perf also